# Rails rest api and associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest

I have 3 tables (elements, categories, relations).
Tables elements and relations have an attribute "id" and "name".
The relations table (relation many to many between elements and categories) has a "type" attribute.

I want to know what is the best way to get one category with all elements related to it and the relation type (it's for a rest api).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I follow exactly.  If you are simply looking for a simpler json/xml response.  Perhaps something like this?

```
class Category
  def relationships
    relations.map { |r| {type: r.type, element: r.element} }
  end

  def serializable_hash(options={})
    defaults = { methods: [:relationships] }

    super(defaults.update(options))
  end
enf

class CategoriesController
  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    render json: @category
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested this but:

my_category = Category.first

```
my_category.relations.each do |relate|
  puts relate.type
  puts "********"
  relate.elements.each do |elem|
    puts elem.name
    puts ""
    puts ""
  end
end
```

of course, if you are rendering this out in a partial or view you would substitute the puts's with appropriate markup.